# Container packing with Java3D

Tags: java, java-3d

So what I am trying to do is to load boxes with different sizes into a big container. I am using the LAFF algorithm to do this and I want to visualize the full loading plan of the container using Java3D . 
My problem is when I try to position packed boxes for each lever , they exceed the container's dimensions and the second level's boxes do not appear on top of the first one's. I attached a new image [image]

and this is the code I wrote for the packing process in Java3D:

```
 VirtualUniverse myUniverse = new VirtualUniverse();
        Locale myLocale = new Locale(myUniverse);
        float p2 = 0;
        BranchGroup nodeRoot = new BranchGroup();
        nodeRoot=buildContentBranch(buildShape(x, y, z));

        //----------------------------------------
        Shape3D backShape = ((Box) buildShape(x, y, z)).getShape(Box.RIGHT);

          int rr = 2;
          System.out.println();
          float[] position = new float[3];
          geo.getCoordinates(rr, position);
          Vector3f pp = new Vector3f (position[0],position[1], position[2]);


        //--------------------------------------------------------
        GeometryArray geo=(GeometryArray)backShape.getGeometry();
        float[] position=new float[3];
        geo.getCoordinate(0, position);
        //geo.getCoordinate(1,position);
        //System.out.println(position[0]+" "+position[1]+" "+position[2]);
       Vector3f pp = new Vector3f (position[0]-0.2f,position[1]+0.3f, position[2]-0.1f);
        Color3f c1=new Color3f(0.7f, .15f, .15f);
        Color3f c2=new Color3f(0.7f, .15f, .15f);
        Color3f[] c=(Color3f[]) new Color3f[20] ; 

            c[0] =new Color3f(Color.getHSBColor(20.f, 30f, 2.f));
            c[1] =new Color3f(Color.BLUE);
            c[2] =new Color3f(Color.YELLOW);
            c[3] =new Color3f(Color.GREEN);
            c[4] =new Color3f(Color.WHITE);
            c[5] =new Color3f(Color.CYAN);
            c[6] =new Color3f(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            c[7] =new Color3f(Color.PINK);
            c[8] =new Color3f(Color.RED);
            c[9] =new Color3f(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            c[10] =new Color3f(Color.MAGENTA);
            c[11] =new Color3f(Color.getHSBColor(0.2f, 0.15f, 2.f));
            c[11] =new Color3f(Color.getHSBColor(0.8f, 0.1f, 15.f));
            c[13] =new Color3f(Color.ORANGE);
            c[11] =new Color3f(Color.getHSBColor(1.f, 0.8f, 2.f));



    //--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        int i=0;
                for (Level level : levels2) {
                  for (Items b : level.packedBoxes) {

                Transform3D transform = new Transform3D();
                transform.setTranslation(pp);
                Box ProductBox = addProductBox(b.dimension.get("length"),b.dimension.get("breadth")
                        ,b.dimension.get("height"),c1, c2,c[i],c[i]);
                Transform3D rotateCube = new Transform3D();
                rotateCube.set(new AxisAngle4d(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, Math.PI / 4.0));
                TransformGroup rotationGroup = new TransformGroup(rotateCube);
                TransformGroup TranslateGroup = new TransformGroup(transform);
                TranslateGroup.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
                rotationGroup.addChild(ProductBox);
                TranslateGroup.addChild(rotationGroup);
                nodeRoot.addChild(TranslateGroup);
                //get the coordinates of the new box 
                Shape3D shape = ProductBox.getShape(Box.FRONT);

            position[0]-= b.dimension.get("length");
            p2=boxBig.dimension.get("height");
           if (position[0]-x>0) {
             position[1]+= b.dimension.get("breadth");

            }
            if (y-position[1]<0)  
            {
                position[2]+=p2;
            }
        i++;
         Vector3f pp2 = new Vector3f (position[0],position[1], position[2]);
         pp=pp2;

       System.out.println("pppppppp  " +pp);
        }
            }
            myLocale.addBranchGraph(nodeRoot);
            setTitle("Container Loading");
            setSize(1000,1000);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add("Center", canvas);
            setVisible(true);
            myLocale.addBranchGraph(buildViewBranch(canvas));
```

I have 8 boxes.
I tried to know what is wrong with my code but I couldn't figure out where the issue is. Can anyone help me with this?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first error that I see is this

```
   position[0]+= b.dimension.get("length");
   p2=boxBig.dimension.get("height");

           System.out.println("position 0 " +position[0]);
        //g.getCoordinate(1,position);
   g.getCoordinate(2,position);
```

You advance the position but then you reread it which will overwrite.

Then pp (if you are using that to position the second object etc) doesnt seem to be advanced inside the inner loop.

That's it for now.

--

After update: I see the lightGray item is hidden so it must be small; and the white one protrudes over two boxes. Maybe the length that you are using to advance the position could be "breadth".

Comment: at least they are moving; there seem 7 objects while you said 8; maybe the colors are not distinct or so. But now you can play and move them apart.